# Find syntax error IN SQL query using python

Tags: python, sql, parsing, module, syntax

I want to parse sql file using python code and find any syntatical error present in the file. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot

```
import sqlglot
sqlglot.parse_one("select (")
>> sqlglot.errors.ParseError: Expecting ). Line 1, Col: 8.
```

select (